# How can I insert data form csv file to OpenTSDB in the fastest possible way?

Tags: hadoop, nosql, hbase, opentsdb

I have a three node Hadoop cluster with Hbase and OpenTSDB. I wonder what is the fastest way to import data from csv file to OpenTSDB. I found some methods in the [official documentation](http://opentsdb.net/docs/build/html/index.html) however I am not sure which one will allow me to achieve the best performance. If any additional information is required, just let me know. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Let's start with what tools you **do** have. Other than HBase and HDFS

Comment: @cricket_007 Sorry for late response, I have just noticed your answer. Do you mean how exactly my cluster looks like?

Comment: Well, do you have Hive? Spark? Pig? Any tool can only read a CSV so quickly. Spark is likely the most flexible

Comment: I don't have any of the tools listed by you. Do you think that Spark will allow me to achieve best performance for importing data from csv file to Hbase or OpenTSDB?

Comment: It'll work. I won't claim "best" anything

Comment: @cricket_007 Do you think that Spark will allow me to achieve better performance for inserting data to Hbase in comparison to `MapReduce` with `Hbase Bulk Loading` and `LoadIncrementalHFiles`?

Comment: I think Spark is more peformant than MapReduce, yes, if you have enough memory/cores to support the data

Comment: @cricket_007 Do you use ansible to configure pyspark for instance on three nodes?

Comment: Sorry, your comments are getting very off-topic from the question. I would use Ansible, yes, to setup Python and Spark

Comment: @cricket_007 So in your opinion I should use Spark instead of MapReduce to import data from HDFS to Hbase or do you suggest using Spark to directly import data from source to Hbase without loading it into HDFS?

Comment: Either sholuld be fine, but I am very unfamiliar with HBase itself

Comment: @cricket_007 Are you familiar with PySpark, Spark Streaming and Kafka?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to ask about them, but maybe would be better as a separate post? Java/Scala would be able to process data faster than PySpark. If you want to load data from Kafka to HBase, I would use Kafka Connect rather than maintain any custom Spark code.